# Divs that hover around

Tags: jquery, hover

i hope i can describe what i want. I'm searching for a jquery solution/plugin that animate divs as they hover around. Little smooth movements in each direction so it seems that the div hover.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks,
Thomas

Comment: You mean make the `<div>` grow when you hover it with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery animate function it should do the trick

Comment: hover is maybe the wrong word... i mean a movement like a bubble in the air

Comment: @Thomas can you give example of existing website with such effect?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with jqrumble when you use a slow speed and a big range: http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

the last time I used jqrumble it didn't work in Internet Explorer, though